# Delta Chat Rust integration in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, android, rust, java-native-interface

i'm currently building a Spring Boot Application and i want to send some Mails via Chat over IMAP. Deltachat implements COI.
DeltaChat offers an API written in RUST.
https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-core-rust

As written here https://support.delta.chat/t/bindings-for-java/970

The Java Bindings should be implemented by the Android App
https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-android/tree/master/src/com/b44t/messenger

Plus I need to get up the JNI:
https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-android/tree/master/jni

I copied the two folders jni and messenger into a separate java project along with deltachat-core-rust Projekt.
However, I am not sure how to connect the Java classes to the C code.
What is the best way to do this?
In the JNI folder there is still the Android.mk class, do I have to implement what is implemented there myself?

---

Update:

Now I have created the shared library with the following code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(deltachat LANGUAGES C)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)

# generate libnative.jnilib
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_library(native MODULE dc_wrapper.c ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deltachat-core-rust/deltachat-ffi/deltachat.h)
#set_target_properties(native PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".jnilib")
target_link_libraries(native ${JNI_LIBRARIES} )
target_link_libraries(native ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deltachat-core-rust/target/release/libdeltachat.a)
```

Is this correct?

When i try to run this:

```
import messenger.DcContext;

public class MainJni {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DcContext dcContext = new DcContext("ubuntu", "example.db");

        if(dcContext == null){

        }
    }


}
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/robin/Documents/DeltaChatCoreJavaBindings/src/jni/build/libnative.so: /home/robin/Documents/DeltaChatCoreJavaBindings/src/jni/build/libnative.so: undefined symbol: SSL_get_error
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2659)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
    at MainJni.<clinit>(MainJni.java:6)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The [`dc_wrapper.c`](https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-android/blob/master/jni/dc_wrapper.c) file contains C functions of the form `Java_com_b44t_*` that implements the `native` methods in the corresponding [Java package](https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-android/tree/master/src/com/b44t/messenger).

In order to get this working on any platform, you need to create a build system (Make, CMake, Xmake, Ninja, ...) that:

1. compiles the Rust crate into a static library;
2. compiles the `dc_wrapper.c` into a dynamically loadable library that is linked with the rust crate.

Finally, you can use the `com.b44t.messenger.*` classes from Java, which should automatically load the library created in step two.
The `android.mk` file is mostly android-specific compile options, so you should not look too hard at it.

Comment: Thank you. :)
Can this be done by this File
https://github.com/deltachat/deltachat-core-rust/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: That looks like it will build the static library, but *only* the static library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/angelo-fuchs/dc-jni-playground, it is not currently maintained, but it could give you some hints to make it work.

That repo is an attempt for making the java bindings usable standalone, not only inside of the deltachat android source code.